# Enviar datos en array a otra página para hacer una consulta php

Tags: javascript, php, html

Buenas tardes, tengo el siguiente select para elegir los temas que quiero elegir para hacer un test de preguntas y pasarlos a otra página php donde hace la consulta de las preguntas de cada tema, es decir, según los temas que elija en el select, me hara un listado de preguntas. Lo que quisiera es pasar ese array de los temas elegidos por POST a dicha página pero no lo consigo:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
    <title>x</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    body{width:600px;margin:0 auto;overflow-x:hiden;}
    select{width:180px;margin:0 0 50px 0;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;}
    .clear{clear:both;text-align:center}
    div{float:left;width:200px;text-align:center}
    input {margin:25px 1px 0 1px;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:10px;}
    .izq{border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;}
    .der{border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pasar opciones de un select list a otro con jQuery</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" id="formulario">
        <div>
            <select name="origen[]" id="origen" multiple="multiple" size="8">
                <option value="1">Tema 1</option>
                <option value="2">Tema 2</option>
                <option value="3">Tema 3</option>
                <option value="4">Tema 4</option>
                <option value="5">Tema 5</option>
                <option value="6">Tema 6</option>
                <option value="7">Tema 7</option>
                <option value="8">Tema 8</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="button" class="pasar izq" value="Pasar &raquo;"><input type="button" class="quitar der" value="&laquo; Quitar"><br />
            <input type="button" class="pasartodos izq" value="Todos &raquo;"><input type="button" class="quitartodos der" value="&laquo; Todos">
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <select name="destino[]" id="destino" multiple="multiple" size="8"></select>
        </div>
        <p class="clear"><input type="submit" class="submit" name"report" value="Procesar formulario"></p>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function() 
    {
        $('.pasar').click(function() { return !$('#origen option:selected').remove().appendTo('#destino'); });  
        $('.quitar').click(function() { return !$('#destino option:selected').remove().appendTo('#origen'); });
        $('.pasartodos').click(function() { $('#origen option').each(function() { $(this).remove().appendTo('#destino'); }); });
        $('.quitartodos').click(function() { $('#destino option').each(function() { $(this).remove().appendTo('#origen'); }); });
        $('.submit').click(function() { $('#destino option').prop('selected', 'selected'); });
    }); 
    </script>
<?php      
if (isset($_POST['report'])) {
foreach ($_POST['report'] as $seleccionado) {
echo $seleccionado; 
} }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrijo, tienes que pasarlos a tu nuevo select y entonces ya solo al enviarlo tienes que recibirlos por metodo post

```
foreach ($_POST['destino'] as $seleccionado) {
echo $seleccionado"; 
}
```

Comment: No me funciona. Acabo de editar la pregunta con el código que pongo.

Comment: Ya lo he editado, copia y reemplaza tu foreach tal cual aparece ahí, en lugar de $_POST['report'],  tiene que ir $_POST['destino'], ya que destino es el nombre de tu select que mandaste por Post

Comment: Funciona. Perfecto muchas gracias por la ayuda!